# Explicit definition for Sn, n>=1, for following infinite sequence of elements (0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1…)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to figure out explicit definition for Sn (Sn is the n-th term, S1=1, S2=2, S3=3 S4=4 ... ), n>=1, for following infinite sequence of elements from the set {0,1}

(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1…)

Any suggestions please?  I see that number of 0s increases by one after each 1 but I can't seem to come up with way to derive the formula. Any tips would greatly help.  Thank you.

Comment: Is Sn meant to be the n-th term, so S1=0, S2=1, S3=S4=0, etc?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally,
if $a(n)$
is a strictly increasing sequence
of positive integers,
we want a sequence
$b(n)$ such that
$b(a(n)) = 1$
and
$b(n) = 0$
otherwise.

In this case,
$a(n)
=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
$.

Let
$c(n)$ be the inverse function
of $a(n)$
so that
$c(a(n)) = n$
and $c(n)$
is strictly increasing
(though not necessarily
integral).

In this case,
$m
=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}
$
so
$4n(n+1) = 8m$
or
$(2n+1)^2 = 8m+1
$
so
$n
=\dfrac{\sqrt{8m+1}-1}{2}
$.
Therefore
$c(n)
=\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}
$.

Since $a(n)$ is 
strictly increasing,
$c(n)$ is increasing,
though not necessarily strictly.
In particular,
for $a(n) \le m \lt a(n+1)$,
$n 
= c(a(n))
\le c(m)
\le c(a(n+1))
=n+1
$
so
$c(m) = n$
for
$a(n) \le m \lt a(n+1)$.

Therefore,
$c(m)$ is an integer
then
$b(m) = 1$
and
$b(m) =0$
otherwise.
Playing around,
this can be written as
$b(m)
=1-\lceil c(m)-\lfloor c(m) \rfloor \rceil
$.

In this case,
$b(m)
=1-\lceil \dfrac{\sqrt{8m+1}-1}{2}-\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{8m+1}-1}{2} \rfloor \rceil
$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
S_n = &
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{if $n$ is of the form $\frac{k^2 - k -2}{2}$ where $k$ is an integer}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \\
= &
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{if $\frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \sqrt{8n +9} \right)$ is an integer}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \\
\end{split}
$$
This is assuming that the sequence starts from $n=1$.

Comment: Hi Matti, thank you for help.  How did you arrive to this formula?  I'm not able to get 1's,0's by plugging into second formula.  Thank you tons for help.

Comment: How I arrived at the formula: I considered the sequence of numbers where $1$ appears: $n=1,3,6, 10, 15 \dots$ (I noticed that you have changed the sequence from yesterday). I immediately recognized that the general formula for finding the $n$'s is akin to the formula for the sum of integers up to $k$, $\sum_{l=1}^k l = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. I just needed to wiggle the terms around a bit to match the given values.

Comment: What's the particular difficulty in the second equation? If we take for example $n=4\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \sqrt{8\times 4 + 9} \right) \approx 3.702$ (not an integer) $\Rightarrow S_4 = 0$. But $n=5\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\left( 1 + \sqrt{8\times 5 + 9} \right) = 4$ (integer) $\Rightarrow S_5 = 1$

Comment: (In the previous comment I assumed the older sequence (0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0, 1,  ... ))